# Firebase delete images from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to delete images from firebase storage (react.js), but when I try to recover the url the console gives me:
***FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'images/[object Object]' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found."
}
}***

This is the code:

```
const deleteFromFirebase = (url) => {
    
        let imageRef = storage.ref(`/images/${url}`);
            
            imageRef.delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Deleted")
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      };
```

I need to insert the index?

Comment: Can you `console.log(url)` right before `imageRef` and share a screenshot of what it is?

Comment: @Dharmaraj https://dropover.cloud/e4a741#622eb5e2-7b84-4385-a5a4-a933bd7569df

Comment: You must pass the path to the file that you want to delete in `ref()` but `url` here seems to be some sort of object. For example if your path is `'/images/image_1.png'`, then value of URL here should have been `image_1.png`. Do you have complete path somewhere ?

Comment: `const uploadTask = await storage.ref(`/images/${imageId}`).put(imageAsFile);
  const imageUrl = await storage.ref('images').child(uploadTask.metadata.name).getDownloadURL();`
I upload and recover url like this when I upload a new image

Comment: Can you pass the imageId in `deleteFromFirebase` ?

Comment: nope... when I try it gives me the same error of 404, because the imageId is inside another function

Comment: In that case, can you share a screenshot of the file that you are trying to delete from Firebase Storage console and also `/images/${url}` and share output of the same? If the paths match then it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

#### The `imageUrl` variable is not a URL

You can prove it by inserting the following `console.log` at the top of your function:

```
const deleteFromFirebase = (url) => {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(url, null, 2);
```

#### And it shouldn't actually be a URL

A URL is a thing like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558620/firebase-delete-images-from-url`. You wouldn't want to be storing your image at the following location, would you?

```
/images/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558620/firebase-delete-images-from-url
```

Therefore I suggest that in your "deleteFromFirebase" function you do not call it a URL, but rather a "pathWithinImagesFolder" or something, that will reduce scope for confusion.

#### Next step is to find out what the firebase storage function is returning

```
const imageUrl = await storage.ref('images').child(uploadTask.metadata.name).getDownloadURL();

console.log("Original value is ",imageUrl)
```

I suspect it is returning an extra-long URL, perhaps with extra things added at the end to give permissions to download, etc.

## My suggestion

Revise all your terminology. There are two separate things.

- pathWithinImages, e.g. `house.png`;
- downloadUrl, e.g. `https://google.something.blahblah/bucketName/blah blah?downloadKey=239850598745`

So when you are uploading, make this clear:

```
const pathWithinImages = uploadTask.metadata.name 
const downloadUrl = await storage.ref('images').child(pathWithinImages).getDownloadURL();
```

Store both the `pathWithinImages` and the `downloadUrl`.

When you come to delete the image, use the `pathWithinImages`.

```
const deleteFromFirebase = (pathWithinImages) => {

    storage.ref(`/images/${pathWithinImages}`)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Deleted")
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  };
```